# SQL Compare date

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys I am trying to compare the local date with one of my query , the problem is that I don't know how to do that .

As I know if we run this

```
SELECT NOW()
```

It will output something like this `2013-03-23 06:56:55`

Now I'd like to update one my row comparing that info but I don't know how to, my idea it's something like this

```
UPDATE `account`.`account` SET `Level` = '1' 
WHERE `Level` = '2' AND Select NOW() >`last_online`
```

What I want to prevent is the fact that I am updating the account and the user is online , so I want to compare the last time online with the current date and then run the query if the current date is > than the last time online

Thanks!

EDIT: The server is mysql

Comment: What flavor of SQL engine are you using?  Best to put that into a Tag, rather than just the question, as that will more efficiently attract experts in that SQL engine.

Comment: unless a process is constantly updating last_online, that logic is somewhat flawed.... maybe subtract an hour....

Comment: last_online is updated constantly that's why I need to check that the user is offline

Comment: How can I substract one hour?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the 2nd SELECT

```
  UPDATE `account`.`account` 
  SET `Level` = '1' 
  WHERE `Level` = '2' AND NOW() > `last_online`
```

Comment: Did you know how can I substract one hour?